# Text stays above minipage

Tags: minipage, pdfpages

I am trying to import a pdf that contains a jupyter notebook cell using the minipage command, but the cell is printed bellow the text "Then we need ... dataset:". How can i keep the flow of the text as i put it in the code ?

```
 \subsection{Approach 1: Scikit-learn}
    We will start by importing the proper libraries:
    
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages=1,width=\textwidth,pagecommand={}]{jupyter_code/imports}
    \end{minipage}
    
    Then we need to import the “Greece - Agriculture and Rural Development” dataset:
```

The result is:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `\includegraphics` here as you do not want a full page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
 \subsection{Approach 1: Scikit-learn}
    We will start by importing the proper libraries:
    
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image.pdf}
    \end{minipage}
 
   Then we need to import the “Greece - Agriculture and Rural Development” dataset:
\end{document}
```

Comment: This moves the pdf to a new page and the text "Then we need to ..." at the end of the first page. Is there anything else that can influence this behavior? For example i am using '\documentclass{book}'.

Comment: @AndrewZacharakis see my example which has no page break. note to can also remove the minipage which is doing nothing useful here. perhaps you need to make a smaller scale= so it fits on the page, as you provided no example hard to say

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer, i will mark it as correct as it solves my answer in general and I will see what else i have messed up :D

Comment: if you can help ... The problem is that the pdf that i have, has a page number and overleaf inserts the whole pdf page, but i just want the jupyter cell

Comment: you can trim the pdf `\includegraphics[scale=0.8,viewport=2cm 2cm 5cm 5cm, clip]{...}`  @AndrewZacharakis (Overleaf isn't really involved they are just hosting a standard texlive system, you would get the same result in any tex installation)